# Finding $M_f(r)$ - maximum modulus of a function $e^{\sin z}$ as a function of $r$ (modulus of a complex-valued number $z$)

Tags: complex-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, derivations, maximum-principle

I'm not asking for a full solution or answer. Please give me a direction in which to get the right answer.

I found in a university book that if a complex-valued function $f$ is holomorphic, then (as $r$ increases) the value of $M_f(r)$ increases monotonically. I will not prove this statement, but just use it for our complex-valued functions $e^{\sin z},$ $e^{\cos z}$, $\sin z,$ $\cos z,$ which are obviously holomorphic.

This is easy to find the maximum modulus of the functions $\cos z$ and $e^{\cos z}$ as a function of $r$ (modulus of a complex-valued number $z$).
But solving a similar example for $e^{\sin z}$ becomes much more difficult. Here is my attempt to solve this problem (it did not lead to the final answer), you can see it in the two attached photos: [1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyUCK.jpg) [2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRpop.jpg)

I will also give backup links to these 2 images on google drive:

1st - drive.google.com/file/d/1kChJ1cX0TOcR9d7U_ufVm6_HyyImxtYm/view

2nd - drive.google.com/file/d/1T6wey4qsyRhbA1wX2HjGMV6gcEtcHN2v/view

Comment: $\sin z = \sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y$ so $|e^{\sin z}| = e^{\sin x\cosh y}$. While $x^2+y^2 = r$, try to maximize $\sin x\cosh y$.